# woocommerce my account page showing posts

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm working on a WordPress plugin where I've to create a custom frontend page. After adding the `add_rewrite_tag`, my custom frontend page works and all the woocommerce pages (endpoints) works fine but the `/my-account` page does not.

It shows the posts page. Removing the `add_rewrite_tag` fixes the /my-account page.

```
function customop_custom_output() {
            add_rewrite_tag( '%pn-projects%', '([^/]+)' );
            add_permastruct( 'pn-projects', '/%pn-projects%' );
            flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'init', 'customop_custom_output' );
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Try refreshing the permalinks in Settings.

Comment: No need to refresh the permalinks from settings as I'm already refreshing the rewrite rule

Comment: You should only be flushing the rewrite rules on plugin activation and deactivation not on init hook.

Comment: I tried that but that seems not to be working. Can I add multiple rewrite_tag?